# i send my monero without payment id

Tags: payment-id

about 1hours 30min ago i sent my monero from bter.com to bittrex.
but i didn't wrote my payment id. bittrex say that i have to wait about 2 weeks
but i am very urgent my money.

can i get some help?
my txid is 80dde5fc0b62cfa8294ab511f76b005e85473e22d8e365ab5d6848f32ce102dd
and amount is 34.2189

and bittrex wallet address is 830666 463tWEBn5XZJSxLU6uLQnQ2iY9xuNcDbjLSjkn3XAXHCbLrTTErJrBWYgHJQyrCwkNgYvyV3z8zctJLPCZy24jvb3NiTcTJ

Answer (score 2):

If you already sent it, you should just wait it out. As long as it's not lost. For faster transactions, you can raise the priority for a higher fee.

Answer (score 1):

The money will arrive to Bittrex. Thing is, without the payment ID, they won't know who to credit it to.

You need to open a ticket with Bittrex, and give them the TXID and exact amount of your deposit, and maybe a screenshot of your Bter withdrawal log.

That should be enough. If they ask for more details (TX key), you're at mercy of Bter to provide you with the details since it's them who made the TX (on your behalf).